# Macbook pro on external FHD Monitor

Tags: macos, external-display, macbook-pro-retina

I'm using a full hd external monitor with my 2014 macbook pro.
With the built-in screen I can choose the "more space" option, I haven't the same on the external screen. 
There is something similar I can do?
On the external monitor everything too large.

Answer (score 1):

Your MacBook has at least a 2560x1600 [13"] screen if not 2880x1800 [15"] - in effect double-density compared to its apparent size.
In 'normal view' each visible pixel is really made up of several real ones.
Setting 'more space' relies on translating that so that fewer real pixels are used to form each visible pixel.

A "Full HD" screen is a mere 1920x1080.
One pixel is one pixel, that's it.
It simply doesn't have any "more space" to play with, that's all it can do.

Comment: Ok, but there is no way to reduce the size of icons? Something to emulate the more space functionality?

Comment: No. To do that you need more pixels. The MBP can do it because the 'Retina' screen starts out with twice as many pixels as the image appears to be using. Your 1080 screen doesn't have any to spare.

Comment: OK, I need a UHD monitor so. What a mess!